# Python Rich: Emojis not showing

Tags: python, rich

```
from rich import print
from rich.console import Console
console = Console()


#example 1
print("Hello, [bold magenta]World[/bold magenta]!", ":vampire:", locals())

#example 2
console = Console()
print("Hello, [bold magenta]World[/bold magenta]!", "")
console.print("Hello", "World!", style="bold red")

#example 3
print(f"I wonder what this looks like 1 + 1 = {1 + 1}")
print({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b" : {"c" : 1}})


#example 4
console.print("This is some text.")
console.print("This is some text.", style="bold")
console.print("This is some text.", style="bold underline")
console.print("This is some text.", style="bold underline red")
console.print("This is some text.", style="bold underline red on black")
 
#example 5
console.print(":thumbs_up: File downloaded!")

input("")
```

so when i run it i get i Am not getting what is the error please help
i am mostly confused with these topics so i dont know what is the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URuVA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic windows console doesn't have good support for emoji. If you install the new [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) you will find your emojis will appear as expected.

Comment: question: normally i would go to the directory of the file i want to open like C:/[user]/desktop (in file explorer) and replace the path with cmd so it would open the path in command prompt can i do that with windows terminal